# Is there any way to cache the theano compiling result?

Tags: theano

I ask this question because the compiling process of theano is quite time consuming, and what making it worse is that each time I run the code, the function will be recompiled. So, is there any way to make theano cache the previous compiling result if there is no code change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Theano already caches compilation results. The cache is stored in `~/.theano` by default but the location and format of the contents can be adjusted via the config flags [`config.base_compiledir`](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/config.html#config.base_compiledir), [`config.compiledir_format`](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/config.html#config.compiledir_format), and [`config.compiledir`](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/config.html#config.compiledir).

If you create a very large computation graph then the first run should be substantially slower than subsequent runs.